# How to handle expandcollapse in radgrid from Telerik UI on the client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid

On server side when I want to handle expand collapse I just add a method:

```
protected void RadGridDataSource_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e){
   if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.ExpandCollapseCommandName){...}
}
```

but how if I want to handle it on client side and invoke a JS method, how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the grid to

```
HierarchyLoadMode="Client"
```

Then you should be able to use client events

```
<ClientSettings Scrolling-AllowScroll="false" Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true" AllowExpandCollapse="true"
     ClientEvents-OnHierarchyExpanded="rgCon_OnHierarchyExpanded"                    
</ClientSettings>

function rgCon_OnHierarchyExpanded(sender, eventArgs){
  //do stuff
}
```